# Maven, Spring, Tomcat. Начальная страница проекта - index работает, остальные - 404 Not Found

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, http-status-code-404, crud

Делал проект один в один, как на видео в ютубе ["Создание CRUD приложения на языке Java с помощью Spring"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7swABdqOS4), и у меня работает только начальная страница, на других 404. Ну и еще там деплой не работает, тоже не знаю как настроить репозиторий, но на видео с этим проблем не было. Ничего из предложенного гуглом не помогает..

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса непонятно, что работает, а что не работает и куда смотреть. Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый код, и укажите какой результат ожидаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам решил проблему, которая заключалась в том, что в папку out/WEB-INF/lib надо было вручную скинуть все библиотеки. Не знаю почему автоматически оно их не кинуло. все dependencies были provided